# Using HiveContext in Maven project

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have built Spark-1.2.1 using Maven to enable Hive support using the following command :
`mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -DskipTests clean package`

which resulted in some class files generated in `/spark-1.2.1/core/target/scala-2.10/classes` folder

Now how do I use this newly built Spark in my `Eclipse + Maven` project? I want to use the Spark-SQL's `HiveContext` class in Eclipse.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you are going to use SparkSQL in java program, you can simply add the appropriate dependencies to your maven project and the required classed would be available to you. Building spark with hive support enables you to start spark daemons with hive support. It generates an assembly jar which needed to copied to all spark worker nodes. For more details please see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)

Maven dependencies for getting HiveContext working:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But when I try to compile using `mvn scala:compile`, I am getting this error:
error: object hive is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

Comment: Use your original command mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phive -DskipTests clean package and copy the generated jar in worker node's lib directory

Comment: Thanks vikas, but it should at least let me compile the project if all the dependencies are met.
The foremost problem is that my Eclipse does not recognize the `org.apache.spark.sql.hive` package even though I have Spark SQL dependency mentioned in the pom.


Can you indicate me where is the worker node's lib directory?

Comment: These are two different things. The command you mentioned for support of HiveContext is needed to support Hive at runtime by spark runtime which requires the built jar to be copied to every worker node. And when you are trying to write a code, which needs to access HiveContext in Java, you need to add maven dependencies of spark-core, spark-sql and spark-hive

Comment: @vikas, when i create HiveContext() where it will look for hive metastore details and how to configure that?

Comment: @Shankar Configuration of Hive is done by placing your hive-site.xml file in conf/. Please refer the link shared in the answer itself.